# Somar uma data e um número x de meses

Tags: php

Meu primeiro post aqui, então se caso digitar alguma coisa errada, já peço desculpas.

Meu problema é o seguinte: Uso um método no PHP pra somar uma data com um número **x de meses**. Por exemplo:

`2017-01-01` + 11 meses

resultado esperado:

`2017-12-01`.

Porém eu preciso de algo que além de trazer o mês somado, que traga também o último dia do mês.

Por exemplo:

`2017-01-0 + 11 meses = 2017-12-31`.

Percebem que o número de dias veio com o ultimo dia de mês de dezembro junto? Então, preciso disso.

A `$data1` sempre ira começar com o dia 01, independente do ano/mês que será buscado.

Atualmente estou utilizando esse código para somar o número de meses com a data:

```
public static function SomarDataMes($data, $meses){

   $data = explode("/", $data);

   $newData = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[1] + $meses, $data[0], $data[2]) );

   return $newData;

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

De certa forma, é simples. Seguindo a lógica: **Soma-se a quantidade de meses, logo após pega último dia do mês.**

```
// Data de ínicio 
$date    = (new DateTime('2017-10-01'));

// Adiciona 2 meses a data
$newDate = $date->add(new DateInterval('P2M')); 

// Altera a nova data para o último dia do mês
$lDayOfMonth = $newDate->modify('last day of this month');


echo $lDayOfMonth->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-12-31
```

Exemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1b428e66c70a7b2129f9153aba4b256d62b779b

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = '2017-01-01';
$months = 11;
$frequency = [
    'DAY',
    'MONTH',
    'YEAR'
];
print date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date. "+".$months." ".$frequency['0']));
```